# Alerting date in javascript through ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

while alerting the date in asp.net with RegisterStartupScript , gives me a decimal value

This is my code

```
"alert("+DateTime.Today.ToString(AgencyDateFormat)+")"
```

result is

```
0.00012413108242303873
```

how can i deal with this. please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is your `AgencyDateFormat`? Can you show more surrounding code?

Comment: it's for converting it to dd/mm/yyyy format, its a db value , so that every user can set their own format, its working fine. everywhere else, gives a string o/p too

Comment: try the answer given below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
"alert("+DateTime.Today.ToString(AgencyDateFormat)+")"
```

to

```
"alert('"+DateTime.Today.ToString(AgencyDateFormat)+"')"
```